# Provide a Windows application to show alerts when questions get answers or comments

Tags: feature-request, alerts

Does the team have, or can it develop, a Windows application to show alerts when designated questions get answered or receive comments?

I need such an app because I sometimes can't open web browsers in my office.

Comment: Check out [Stack Apps](http://stackapps.com/) to see if there is one already.

Comment: If you can't browse to Stack Overflow from your office, you probably wouldn't be able to access the API either :(

Comment: check this link helpful http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f

Comment: If you can't browse it then what's the benefit of knowing it's changed anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at either the [StackWatcher](https://stackapps.com/q/1149/401) or [StackApplet](https://stackapps.com/q/83/401) applications on StackApps which might meet your needs.

Note though that it will still need access to the Stack Overflow site to get this information - if this is blocked by your corporate firewall you won't be able to use this app.